# react native - how to make list that update automatically

Tags: react-native

I want to automatically update a list from one screen to another in a react-native app, from 1 to 80.

When I press the button on the createUserScreen to create a list, I can then travel to the dashboardScreen and the list there will automatically update much as the list on the createUserScreen.

Try to solve the issue on my own with a little assistance from chatGPT,
and look for solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contexts and provider to make a state accessible in multiple components

https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext